# How do I get photos from my iphone to the iPad in my husbands name via icloud

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos

Our iPad is in my husbands name, but I have a new iphone. How can I get my photos to appear on the iPad using icloud?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that the iPad has one Apple ID (your husband's) in `Settings > iCloud` and your iPhone has a *different* Apple ID (yours) in `Settings > iCloud`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a shared photostream, share with your husband's account, and add whatever pics you want to that stream.

Go into photos app, tap photostream tab at bottom, then use the plus at top to add a new stream. He will get an invite when you create it that enables him to link to that photo stream on the iPad.

To add pics, simply press and hold one of your photos until the options pop up and add it to your photostream.